# How to set up an align in table column DITA

Tags: xml, pdf, dita

I am using DITA to make pdfs.

So, on creating a table I can set up it's text to be aligned left, but I need few columns to be centered. Now I have to click every entry to set up options.

Question is: how can I align to center whole column without clicking on every entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify the align attribute at the colspec element. An example:

```
<table frame="all" rowsep="1" colsep="1" id="table_lcx_k4j_wy">
<title/>
<tgroup cols="4">
 <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="1.0*" align="left"/>
 <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="1.0*" align="center"/>
 <colspec colname="c3" colnum="3" colwidth="1.0*" align="left"/>
 <colspec colname="c4" colnum="4" colwidth="1.0*" align="center"/>
 <thead>
  <row>
   <entry>Header 1</entry>
   <entry>Header 2</entry>
   <entry>Header 3</entry>
   <entry>Header 4</entry>
  </row>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <row>
   <entry>Text</entry>
   <entry>Text</entry>
   <entry>Text</entry>
   <entry>Text</entry>
  </row>
 </tbody>
</tgroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify the column alignment, in table 'colspecs'.